# How to use ASPxGridView without client scripts and postback data

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I added DevExpress GridVIew into my ASP .NET WebForms app. GridView works fine but it generates a huge hidden input with base64-encoded postback data and loads several large javascript files. I don't need any client-side functionality. So, how to disable client-side functionality of this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the grid from creating this hidden field, set the [ASPxGridView.EnableRowsCache](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_EnableRowsCachetopic) property to false.  It is impossible to turn off java script, sorry.